# Creating decentralized identity

Tags: decentralization, identity

I did read some questions like [How does Ethereum enable self sovereign identity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3950/how-does-ethereum-enable-self-sovereign-identity) but I was wondering if someone could advise me how to get started with the technical aspects of creating a decentralized identity? I see no projects/white-paper that highlight the codes of how to develop such ID!

Thanks for the suggestions and sorry if the question was rather stupid!

Answer (score 3):

[Your question is quite broad, and may get flagged as such... ]

Have a look at [uPort](https://www.uport.me/), the white paper for which is entitled "[uPort: A Platform for Self-Sovereign Identity](https://whitepaper.uport.me/uPort_whitepaper_DRAFT20170221.pdf)". It contains some pseudo-code, which might help generate some ideas.

Anything on Consensys's official media stream containing the "[identity](https://media.consensys.net/tagged/identity)" tag might also be helpful.

Also of interest would be the new [ERC-725](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/725) contract standard, entitled "Identity". From the EIP abstract:

> The following describes standard functions for a unique identity for
>   humans, groups, objects and machines. This identity can hold keys to
>   sign actions (transactions, documents, logins, access, etc), and
>   claims, which are attested from third parties (issuers) and self
>   attested, as well as a proxy function to act directly on the
>   blockchain.